# Jenkins .net project build error, sh command

Tags: .net, jenkins, .net-core

I am new to Jenkins. I am trying to build a Dotnet core project, which the repository is github.
I have provided the github url,local git path, github credentials etc. MSBuild path also I have configured.
I have used the parameter /t:Restore for restoring nuget packages.
The nuget restore was successfull, at least it looks so.

I am facing a build error in jenkins due to "sh" command.

Here is output from jenkins[image: e adde]

```
 Installed:
  217 package(s) to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnetcore\shoppingcart.csproj
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnetcore\shoppingcart.sln"   (Restore target(s)).

Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:23.92
[dotnetcore] $ sh -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins3551322773556983091.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnetcore"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

What is this "sh" command, why is it coming, I am not sure.
can anybody throw any light on this.

Comment: Please, share you build step command

Comment: You are trying to execute 'sh' on a windows machine which won't work. Like @PavelAnikhouski already said please provide your stage / pipeline, otherwise it will be difficult to find the issue.

Comment: `sh -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins3551322773556983091.sh` this line means that Jenkins creates a temp file with your build step to execute. Actually, you are trying to run shell command on windows machine. Make sense to use cmd or PS

Comment: Thanks to all of you, the build is successful. actually there was an unnecessary build step .
But what I did not understand is, if the build is successful, which the mesage says, then where is the build output?